# Protractor using file://

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm not sure if I am using it exactly in the correct way as I can't see much documentation around this feature. But I saw that there is the possibility of using `file://` as the `baseUrl` option.

Now I am using Chrome in order to run my Protractor tests and wanting to run them whilst not running against a server as there really isn't any need for the implementation. When running Protractor with this configuration it can't seem to get the file the only thing that happens is that the address comes up with

`data:text/html,<html></html>`

Which then leaves me with the following output

```
Failures:

  1) Test that my App can get Mocked data Should be on the correct page
   Message:
     Error: Timed out waiting for page to load after 10000ms
Wait timed out after 10062ms
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Timed out waiting for page to load after 10000ms
Wait timed out after 10062ms
==== async task ====
Timed out waiting for page to load after 10000ms
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/nwhite/Sites/apibyexample/abe-protractor/tests/e2e/app/myTestApp.spec.js:3:17)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: beforeEach()
Error
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/nwhite/Sites/apibyexample/abe-protractor/tests/e2e/app/myTestApp.spec.js:2:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nwhite/Sites/apibyexample/abe-protractor/tests/e2e/app/myTestApp.spec.js:1:63)

Finished in 12.435 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

Shutting down selenium standalone server.
```

Is there any documentation available around this? is it possible using Chrome as I could only see something mention `node-webkit`? Is there any different configuration options that I need to implement?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Problem for your use case is Protractor doing `self.driver.executeScript('return window.location.href;')` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/714e4e28ab90fb5dfeca4375a68469ef609e2722/lib/protractor.js#L1229)

Given no JS will be possible to execute on a `file://` even if you try hacking Protractor and commenting that section something else will break later.

So seems that using `file://` as a `baseUrl` is a dead-end.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/830f51128d1ca6c8858c99617b2752172044a752  suggests it does its in the changelog file

Comment: You're right. Let's wait for Julie or Hank to jump in.

Comment: I have debugged it a little further and thought would put in here, that I've created a PR https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1391

Comment: So setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` before the `file://` test isn't enough?

Comment: That does make it work but my thought for doing the PR is that it's a necessity when using file so, to prevent a user from having to know to do that as there is no documentation around any of it as far as I can see anyway.